# How to fill the image within ImageView by maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: android, user-interface

I saw many questions on this same topic and tried by using

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

still my image is displaying as it is.If I change the

> android:scaleType="fitCenter"

to
`fitXY` working fine.But as per document this one not maintains aspect ratio.So How can I change the code to work as expected?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/card" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/idImage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/783454" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

![enter image description here][1]
![enter image description here][2]
Where iam missing the concept?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: like second screen with maintaining aspect ratio.

Comment: You...can't. Maintaining aspect ratio, the left image is as large as it can get. To get it taller, you'd have to make it wider than the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this code, this is how I was scaling bitmaps to fit screen properly. Maybe it will be helpful and give you ideas regarding to your task.

```
private void loadImage() {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Bitmap imageBitmap = ... load original image bitmap;  

    Bitmap scaledBitmap = imageBitmap; 

    // Scaling

    int imgSrcHeight = imageBitmap.getHeight();
    int imgSrcWidth = imageBitmap.getWidth();

    int scaledHeight = 0;
    int scaledWidth = 0;

    int ctnrHeight = imageView.getMeasuredHeight();
    int ctnrWidth = imageView.getMeasuredWidth();

    int mHeight = imgSrcHeight - ctnrHeight;
    int mWidth = imgSrcWidth - ctnrWidth;

    if(mHeight > 0 && mWidth > 0)
    {
        if(mHeight > mWidth)
        {
            // scale to fit height
            if(mHeight > 0)
            {
                scaledHeight = ctnrHeight;

                // if height < 0 it means it's already inside of content
                int coefOverhight = (ctnrHeight * 100)/imgSrcHeight;
                scaledWidth = (int)(imgSrcWidth * ((coefOverhight)/100.0)); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // scale to fit width
            if(mWidth > 0)
            {
                scaledWidth = ctnrWidth;
                int coefOverwidth = (ctnrWidth * 100)/imgSrcWidth;
                scaledHeight = (int)(imgSrcHeight * ((coefOverwidth)/100.0));
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        scaledHeight = imgSrcHeight;
        scaledWidth = imgSrcWidth;
    }

    scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, true);


    imageView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
```

}